# Does the sequence $s_n=\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)^{n+1}$ converge to $e$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> How to prove that a sequence where 
>   $$s_n= \left(1+\frac1{n}\right)^{n+1}$$ 
>   converges to $e$?

I know how to prove $(1+1/n)^n$, but I could not prove this.

I already proved that it is monotonically increasing, but I could not prove its boundedness and converging property.

Please explain.

Comment: As written the sequence converges to $e+1$. I assume you refer to

$$s_n = \left(1 + \frac 1 n \right)^{n+1}$$

instead? If so, note that

$$s_n = \left(1 + \frac 1 n \right)^n \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)$$

On the premise each converges and the limit overall does too (remains to be proven - bound $s_n$ above, perhaps?), you can instead have a product of limits as opposed to a limit of a product, which would be $e \cdot 1$.

Comment: Most of the time the limit of this (converging) sequence is defined as $e$. How did you define it?

Comment: $\left(1 + \frac 1 n \right)^{n+1}$ is monotonically *decreasing* towards $e$ while $\left(1 + \frac 1 n \right)^{n}+1$ is monotonically *increasing* towards $e+1$

Answer (score 5):

By the product rule for limits (since both limits exist individually) we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}=\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right] \times \left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1}\right] = e\times 1.$$